# send and retrieve key-value pair between php and jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i use $.get to run php file. how can i send key-value pair (eg. variables) from the php-file to jquery? and when sent, how can i retrieve them with jquery? i want to validate eg. if(key == value) in jquery.

and what is the difference between $.getJSON and $.get? if i want to run php i cannot use $.getJSON?

i tried in the php file use:

```
     echo '{"url": 1}';
```

i also tried:

```
    $json['url'] = 2;
    echo json_encode($json);
```

and in jquery file i use:

```
     alert(data.url);
```

but it didnt work. it displayed "undefined".

what is wrong

Comment: @fayer: 14 questions in 2 days and none of the answers marked as correct? It is considered proper courtesy around here to mark the correct answers as "answered".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`$.getJSON()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) with PHP. Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON("/some/script.php", function(data) {
    alert(data.url);
  });
});
```

On the PHP side use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$array = array('url' => 'http://www.google.com');
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Cletus's response answers your question, though I just wanted to point out the difference between `$.get` and `$.getJSON`.

It's very simple really:

```
// $.get is a shortcut for this:
$.ajax({
    method: "get"
});

// $.getJSON is just a shortcut for this:
$.ajax({
    method: "get",
    dataType : "json"
})
```

They're both just convenience-methods which pre-fill some of the parameters for you.

Comment: Yes, all the jQuery ajax methods are just shortcuts for $.ajax().

Comment: but what is the difference then between ajax with no dataType row and the other one with it? i mean, if i send back json key-value-pairs with json, will it work with the first method?